# How can I overflow this buffer in c programm using fgets?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 int x;

 

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
 char buffer[2];

 x = 0;
 puts("please enter text\n");
 fgets(buffer, 200, stdin);
 printf("You have entered: " );
 printf( buffer );
printf("\nhidden->%d",x);

 }
```

no matter the input it doesnt overflow it spits out text 20+ length and i cant understand why,how can i overflow it (the char buffer[2])?
it was compiled with

```
`gcc -g -O0 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -m32 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack` -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 test.c && mv a.out test.o
```

Comment: Any time you read more than 2 characters (either 1 + `'\n'` or 2 chars), you write beyond the end of `buffer` invoking *Undefined Behavior*. What you will see is anyone's guess, it's *Undefined*.  What is your input you are trying to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buffer did overflow, but maybe you didn't see it. Note that `buffer` is on the stack, and the overflow occurs there. The variable `x` isn't allocated on the stack, so there's a few chances that it is affected by the overflow.

With the code slightly modified, you'll be able to see the overflow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x;
    char buffer[2];

    x = 0;
    puts("please enter text\n");
    fgets(buffer, 200, stdin);
    printf("You have entered: " );
    printf( buffer );
    printf("\nhidden->%d",x);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT: See comments, which are all perfectly right.

Comment: You are trying to test an undefined behavior by using undefined behavior. There is no guarantee the `x` variable is allocated after the `buffer` (it might not even exist in a main memory) so this test may or may not detect the overflow.

Comment: "you'll be able to see the overflow" -> "there is a chance you'll see the overflow"